# use strict, use warnings, use diagnostics - can't find package file CLion

Tags: perl, warnings, clion, strict

I have intentionally omitted a quotation mark to check if `use diagnostics;` is working. The code is a simple Hello World program :

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

print "Hello world";
```

Here is an image of the warning [image]

As you can see, it is working. So my question is how to deal with this yellow color over the pragma.

Comment: it might be a useful information to add, if you are using a plugin for Perl support?

Comment: yes, I am using this - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796-perl. Probably the plugin is broken